# Refresh dataTable after ajax submit

Tags: jquery, laravel, datatable

Currently my dataTable jquery is getting the data from `compact`

My Blade : **task.blade.php**

```
                    $.ajax({
                        headers:{'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
                        url: "{{ route('task_save') }}",
                        method: "POST",
                        data:{
                            proceed:"TRUE",
                            task_title:task_title,
                            weight:weight,
                            desc:desc
                        }, 
                        dataType: "json",
                        success:function(data)
                        {
                            if(data.success.length > 0){
                                refreshTable();
                                toastr.success(data.success[0]);
                                // alert(data.success[0]);              
                            }else{
                                toastr.error(data.error[0]);
                                // alert(data.error[0]);
                            }
                        },
                        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                            console.log(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
                        }
                    });
```

My **TaskController**

```
$task_record = TaskModel::orderBy('created_at','desc')
->get();

return view('admin.task', compact('task_record'))->render();
```

and in my `task.blade.php` In used this `include('admin.taskDatatable')`

Since my datatable is coded inside of this file : `taskDatatable.blade.php`

Here's my **taskDatatable.blade.php**

```
<table id="dtMaterialDesignExample" class="table table-striped" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th class="th-sm">Task Title
        </th>
        <th class="th-sm">Task Description
        </th>
        <th class="th-sm">Weight %
        </th>
        <th class="th-sm">Created By
        </th>
        <th class="th-sm">Created Date
        </th>
        <th class="th-sm">Action
        </th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="taskRcrd">
            @if(count($task_record) > 1)
            @foreach($task_record as $field)
            <tr>
            <td>{{$field->task_title}}</td>
            <td>{{$field->task_desc}}</td>
            <td>{{$field->weight}}</td>
            <td>{{$field->updated_by}}</td>
            <td>{{$field->created_at}}</td>
            <td></td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
            @else
            <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            </tr>
            @endif
    </tbody>

    </table>
```

Here's my `refreshTable()`

```
 <script>
 function refreshTable() {
     $("#dtContainer" ).load(" #dtMaterialDesignExample");
 }
 </script>
```

I'm trying to refresh the dataTable after the success of ajax

the Datatable refresh fine but the whole datatable doesn't work anymore like `pagination, search text, show entries` it means all of the features of datatable not working properly but the data successfully refresh.

**UPDATED**

after trying this code

```
<script>
 function refreshTable() {
$("#dtMaterialDesignExample").DataTable().ajax.reload()
}
</script>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: The best approach I know do to this is to load the data initially with JS, maybe you can use an ajax call to load the data. That way, when you've performed an update, just call the function that loads the data

Comment: Can u refer some links?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [reload datatable after ajax success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38877837/reload-datatable-after-ajax-success)

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
function refreshTable(){
    $("#dtMaterialDesignExample").DataTable().ajax.reload();
}
```

And you don't need to make function for it you can directly call it in **success** function

```
success:function(data)
{
    if(data.success.length > 0){
        $("#dtMaterialDesignExample").DataTable().ajax.reload();
        toastr.success(data.success[0]);

    }else{
        toastr.error(data.error[0]);

    }
},
```

check more info about `ajax.reload()` [ajax.reload()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload())

Check with ajax [reload-refresh-table-after-event](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/38969/reload-refresh-table-after-event)

Comment: As you update your question I see you are loading table on load. your data is coming while loading page from PHP not from ajax. So `ajax.reload();` function works on if your datatable loaded with ajax. If you're using laravel try to use Yajra datatable which creates a JSON for you.https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/master/installation

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
function refreshTable(){
var table =  $('#tableId');
table.DataTable().ajax.reload();
}
```

Comment: DataTables warning: table id=dtMaterialDesignExample - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1

gave me an error

Comment: are you sure the id is 'dtMaterialDesignExample'?

Comment: Yes in the code I already posted. id="dtMaterialDesignExample'"

Comment: Please update the question with the data table code

Comment: Check the updated question to see the image and what I've tried

Comment: Could you try to display the response?

Comment: Can you try to change  `proceed:"TRUE"` to false or remove it.

Comment: I have validation on the controller that may affect the saving of data if I remove the `proceed:"TRUE"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200587/discussion-between-eyad-jaabo-and-king-rg).

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
success: function (data) {
    $('#form').trigger("reset");
}
```

https://www.tutsmake.com/laravel-5-8-datatables-ajax-crud-tutorial/